# can't POST to DocDB collection via Lambda (GET works fine)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

Here is the Lambda:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  // Connection URI for the DocumentDB cluster
  const uri =
    'mongodb://<username>:<password>@docdb-2023-06-08-15-56-01.cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017';

  try {

    // Extract key variables
    const userID = event.pathParameters?.user_id
    const routeKey = (event as any).routeKey
    // let reqBody = (event.body) && JSON.parse(event.body)

    // Create a new MongoClient
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
      tls: true,
      tlsCAFile: 'global-bundle.pem', // Specify the DocDB cert
    });

    let body = {}

    // Connect to the DocumentDB cluster
    await client.connect();

    // Select the database and collection to perform the find operation
    const database = client.db('test');

    // Grab all of the collections I might need
    const loads = database.collection('loads');
    const damages = database.collection('damages');
    const vins = database.collection('vins');
    const deliveries = database.collection('deliveries');

    switch (routeKey) {
      case "GET /all":


        // Perform the find operation
        const loadArr = await loads.find().toArray();
        const damagesArr = await damages.find().toArray();
        const vinsArr = await vins.find().toArray();
        const deliveriesArr = await deliveries.find().toArray();

        const allArr = [...loadArr, ...damagesArr, ...vinsArr, ...deliveriesArr]

        body = {
          routeKey,
          allArr
        }
        break;
      case "GET /dispatch/{user_id}":
        null
        break;
      case "POST /upload_load":
        const uploadedLoad = await loads.insertOne(<hard-coded perfectly formatted object>)
        body = {
          message: "Load successfully uploaded",
          data: uploadedLoad
        };
        break;
    }



    // Close the connection
    await client.close();

    // Return a successful response
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the operation
    console.error('Error:', error);

    // Return an error response
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: 'Error retrieving documents',
        message: error
      }),
    };
  }
};
```

I am relatively confident it's not an issue with my connection since the GET route works as intended - connecting to the "loads" collection as well as the others and returning the correct information from the "test" database.

However, when I hardcode an object that matches the exact schema, and try to POST to the same collection, I get this error message:

```
{"error":"Error retrieving documents","message":{"ok":0,"code":301,"operationTime":{"$timestamp":"7246826669896368129"}}}
```

I have tried creating a new user to ensure that they have readWrite permission for the test database, but I still continue to get this error. I have also double-checked my lambda permissions policies (AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole & AmazonDocDBFullAccess).

Answer (score 0):

solved - I needed "retryWrites:false" when initiating the MongoClient

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).